# Customizing TextField border, label, and hover color in Material-UI v5 with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI v5 with Next.js, and I'm trying to customize the border, label, and hover color of the TextField components. I'm not sure how to apply these customizations properly using CSS instead of the sx prop in Material-UI v5. Can someone provide an example of how to achieve this?

```css
.textField {
  --border-color: white;
  --label-color: white;
}

.textField label {
  color: var(--label-color);
}

.textField input {
  color: var(--label-color);
}

.textField fieldset {
  border-color: var(--border-color);
}
```

So far I have been able to change the colours of the border and text using the above however I am not sure how to change the on hover and on focus colours.